# GAE: error after specifying new indexes: Property x is corrupt in the datastore; it has multiple values, but is not marked as multiply valued

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just manually specified some additional indexes for and then deployed to an existing app (Python SDK v1.7.5, using the DB Datastore), along the lines of the "Advanced Search" idea at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

The indexes are built, but now I get this error for some queries that touch a particular entity's property, X, which is defined as a `db.StringProperty`:

> "Error: Property X is corrupt in the datastore; it has multiple values, but is not marked as multiply valued."

Does this mean that at least one of the entities in the datastore has had X set to a list instead of a string?

I thought this, and ran `create_bulkloader_config`, which analyses the datastore. For the entity in question, it said:

```
- property: X
  external_name: X
  # Type: String Stats: 5031 properties of this type in this kind.
```

Comment: A search on Google for the error gives only the source code: https://www.google.com/search?q=appengine%20Error%3A%20Property%20is%20corrupt%20in%20the%20datastore%3B%20it%20has%20multiple%20values%2C%20but%20is%20not%20marked%20as%20multiply%20valued.%22#q=appengine+Property+is+corrupt+in+the+datastore%3B+it+has+multiple+values%2C+but+is+not+marked+as+multiply+valued.

Comment: Chances are you have changed a model definition at some point and changed a property type from repeated to string and you didn't update underlying data

Comment: @TimHoffman I can't think or see when it has changed. And the analysis from `create_bulkloader_config` says all the values are strings?

Comment: @TimHoffman Also, it wasn't clear in the question, so I have edited it: we are using the DB Datastore, not NDB.

Comment: How many entities do you have.  I doubt bulkloader will examine every entity.

Comment: You could run a process that examines all entities at the raw level retrieve them without using the model.

Comment: An example of retrieving raw entities can be seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970

Comment: @TimHoffman I ran an analysis on the Interactive Console on the server (quicker than the remote_api from the UK) using the code at http://pastebin.com/E5TEcvKL - all the entities were in `set([<type 'unicode'>, <type 'NoneType'>])` . So it must be something else? Or are the NoneTypes the problem?

Comment: I doubt NoneType is a problem, the error is pretty specific. Are you certain you have less than 2000 records ?

Comment: @TimHoffman I was setting those constants on multiple runs to manually avoid the soft memory limit and the request deadlines. I think I have the solution though... I will post the answer below. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error was having indexes that specify the property in question twice, namely:

```
kind: MyEntity
properties:
- name: X
- name: X

kind: MyEntity
properties:
- name: X
- direction: desc
  name: X
```

(These were automatically generated within a list of ~20 indexes.)

Removing these from `index.yaml` and then calling `appcfg.py vacuum_indexes` on the app in question fixed the issue.