# Switching from StringProperty to StringProperty(repeated=True)

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm switching my data model slightly. I was going to add 'repeated=True' to a currently existing stringProperty. I'm wondering if that will mess anything up?

Answer (score 4):

It should work, except perhaps unless you have None values. The on-disk representation of a singleton property value is almost the same as that of a repeated property with one item, and while there's one bit difference (search the NDB source code for 'multiple') that bit is ignored when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

StringProperty() is a string, and StringProperty(repeated=True) is a list of strings.

'foo' vs ['foo']

You will most certainly run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to perform some form of schema migration.  If you don't have two many entities - say less than 10,000 then using the remote_api is probably the easiest.  See this question, [Migrating data when changing an NDB field's property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970)  - I included some code in the answer that allows you to retrieve the raw entities without using the model.  This allows you to manipulate the underlying data - in your case change the string to a list of strings.

I stand corrected.  Sorry.  More significant changes will require migration.