# Can I change a the type of a property in db.Model in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a server running on GAE and data under this model :

```
class A(db.Model):
  a = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Given the data I receive I think I 'a' should be `db.StringProperty()`. What would happen if I make the change ? Is that permitted ?

I looked everywhere on AppEngine's doc for how to update models. It says things about adding new properties (which I will do as plan B) but not about that kind of things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating data when changing an NDB field's property type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer on migrating properties.

[Migrating data when changing an NDB field's property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970)

Its for ndb, but db works the same way.

Sometime you don't need to do anything (ie going from ndb.StringProperty() to ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True).  But in your case you will need to migrate.