# App Engine with Java a specific entry in datastore is breaking my app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a application in appengine that stopped working because of a specific record.

```
com.rga.google.creativesandbox.service.CampaignService findCachedJson: Operation failed...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$V3KeyBatcher.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$V3KeyBatcher.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:102)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.next(Batcher.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.next(Batcher.java:151)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$V3Batcher.makeCalls(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:91)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchGet(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:303)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:280)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.get(WrappedDatastoreService.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.getCollectionFromDatastoreObject(FetchFieldManager.java:666)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField(FetchFieldManager.java:483)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:405)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2353)
    at com.rga.google.creativesandbox.entity.Campaign.jdoReplaceField(Campaign.java)
    at com.rga.google.creativesandbox.entity.Campaign.jdoReplaceFields(Campaign.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceNonLoadedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1992)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchNonLoadedFields(EntityUtils.java:977)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2899)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1014)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:121)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.closingConnection(StreamingQueryResult.java:90)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractQueryResult.java:108)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.disconnect(StreamingQueryResult.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery$1.transactionPreClose(JPQLQuery.java:220)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection.transactionPreClose(DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:179)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2.transactionPreCommit(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:323)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:398)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:287)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityTransaction.commit(JPAEntityTransaction.java:103)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.afterCommit(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:447)
```

I believe that the error is because of a "None" value in a property of list type

```
campaignResources
value: [datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Campaign', 5398208297566208L, u'CampaignResource', 5629499534213120L, _app=u's~creativesandbox-prod', namespace=u'google_creativesandbox_2013'), None, datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Campaign', 5398208297566208L, u'CampaignResource', 5707702298738688L, _app=u's~creativesandbox-prod', namespace=u'google_creativesandbox_2013'), datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Campaign', 5398208297566208L, u'CampaignResource', 6270652252160000L, _app=u's~creativesandbox-prod', namespace=u'google_creativesandbox_2013')]
type: list
```

Datastore view does not allow me to change a property of list type...and I can`t retrieve by app. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is you could grab the python SDK, and use the remote_api_shell to retrieve the raw entity and modify it directly , and write it back. See docs on using the remote_api_shell https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api

Then

This SO question and answer [Migrating data when changing an NDB field's property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970) has some code, that can be used to retrieve the raw entity.

import this code into the python remote_api_shell.

Construct the key using ndb or db. Fetch then modify and write back

For instance the session in the shell would look something like this.

```
> from some_file import get_entities, put_entities
> k = ndb.Key.from_path(u'Campaign', 5398208297566208L, u'CampaignResource', 5629499534213120L, namespace=u'google_creativesandbox_2013')
> x = get_entities([k.to_old_key()])
> x[0]['the property name'] = []
> put_entities[x]
```