# Changing properties of an entity in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Our facilities ticket request system has been live, but now we would like to edit the properties associated with the type of request entity (requesttype).  When I change the line:

```
requesttype = db.StringProperty(verbose_name="Request Type*",choices=(["Bulky Item Disposal","Carpentry","Ceiling,Doors","Electrical","Elevator","Fire Equipment","Groundskeeping","Hazardous Waste","HVAC","Kitchen Equipment","Lighting,Painting","Plumbing","Recycling","Refrigeration","Too Cold","Too Hot","Trash","Vehicle Maintenance","Water Leak","Windows","Other"]))
```

To

```
requesttype = db.StringProperty(verbose_name="Request Type*",choices=(["Bulky Item Disposal","Carpentry","Ceiling","Doors","Electrical","Elevator","Fire Equipment","Groundskeeping","Hazardous Waste","HVAC","Kitchen Equipment","Lighting","Locksmith","Painting","Plumbing","Recycling","Refrigeration","Too Cold","Too Hot","Trash","Vehicle Maintenance","Water Leak","Windows","Other"]))
```

I am given the following error within the Log;

```
Property requesttype is u'Ceiling,Doors'; must be one of ['Bulky Item Disposal', 'Carpentry', 'Ceiling', 'Doors', 'Electrical', 'Elevator', 'Fire Equipment', 'Groundskeeping', 'Hazardous Waste', 'HVAC', 'Kitchen Equipment', 'Lighting', 'Locksmith', 'Painting', 'Plumbing', 'Recycling', 'Refrigeration', 'Too Cold', 'Too Hot', 'Trash', 'Vehicle Maintenance', 'Water Leak', 'Windows', 'Other']
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
        rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
        rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
        return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
        return handler.dispatch()
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
        return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~mma-facreq/6.372062129927600214/main.py", line 158, in get
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~mma-facreq/6.372062129927600214/html/manage.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends "html/base.html" %}
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~mma-facreq/6.372062129927600214/html/base.html", line 41, in top-level template code
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~mma-facreq/6.372062129927600214/html/manage.html", line 14, in block "content"
        {% for x in reqs %}
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2326, in next
        return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1438, in from_entity
        return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 970, in __init__
        prop.__set__(self, value)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
        value = self.validate(value)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2841, in validate
        value = super(StringProperty, self).validate(value)
      File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 646, in validate
        (self.name, value, self.choices))
    BadValueError: Property requesttype is u'Ceiling,Doors'; must be one of ['Bulky Item Disposal', 'Carpentry', 'Ceiling', 'Doors', 'Electrical', 'Elevator', 'Fire Equipment', 'Groundskeeping', 'Hazardous Waste', 'HVAC', 'Kitchen Equipment', 'Lighting', 'Locksmith', 'Painting', 'Plumbing', 'Recycling', 'Refrigeration', 'Too Cold', 'Too Hot', 'Trash', 'Vehicle Maintenance', 'Water Leak', 'Windows', 'Other']
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code used to change the properties associated with the request entity

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you had a typo in your original code, used it to save some datastore entries, and then updated your code to fix it.

You must now have some entries in the datastore that contain "Ceiling,Doors" as a requesttype.  When they get fetched, they cause an error, since that's not a legitimate request type anymore.

To fix this, you'll basically need to add "Ceiling,Doors", "Ceiling", "Doors" to the choices, then update all the entities in your datastore that have "Ceiling,Doors" to the appropriate, value.  After you've done that, you can remove "Ceiling,Doors" as a choice.

Comment: Or use the remote api and modify the raw values to reflect the choices.  This can be done with out deploying new code, however seeing you are getting errors, it will probably be best to do as per @dragonx, deploy code with the additional validated values.  Personally I don't think using Choices for StringProperty is a good  idea unless your pretty sure you will never alter the choices (especially change/remove existing values).

Comment: ^ That should be an and.  Yes, remote API is likely an easier way to do it if you don't have a huge number of entities.  You'll still need to update your model or remote API will still barf on processing your entities, unless you use the low level API to update the entities.

Comment: ;-)  I find the low level api, often the most convenient for altering underlying types especially if you have 10's of thousands or so entities.

Comment: The low level isn't documented on the GAE docs site, you'll have to look in the SDK in google/appengine/api/datastore.py
btw @TimHoffman, have you ever actually used the remote API for 10'x of thousands of entities?  It seems like it would be painfully slow

Comment: Yes I know it isn't documented.  See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970  where I provide an example of using the low level api.  And yes I have processed tens of thousands of records via remote_api.  It is slow, however it does mean you can gradually process stuff over days, and not blow out a processing budget - useful if you don't have access to the billing C/C to get the budget increased. Actually 10000 entities isn't to slow, typically only a few minutes.  Especially using batch gets/puts.