# Python ndb ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Am trying to retrieve an entity from the `datastore`, and then add a value to one of its properties but am getting an error saying

`ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Am performing this operation from a `RequestHandler`.This is my code

```
class AddNewEmployeeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    employee_name = self.request.get('employee_id')
    callback =self.request.get('callback')
    employee = Employee.get_by_id(employee_name)
    if employee:
        self.error(409)
    else:
        dept = Department.get_or_insert(key_name="Other Charges")
        dept.employees.append(employee)
        dept.put()
```

`Other Charges` is the id/name of an entity that already exists in the datastore, `employees` is a property of the `Department` class defined as

`employees =ndb.keyProperty(repeated=True)`

and i am getting the value of `employee_id` from a form.I have tried to find the solution to this online but i discovered that the error is thrown for a whole lot of reasons none of which is similar to my problem.Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

**Edit**
[image]

Comment: My bet is you added some entities with `employees =ndb.keyProperty()` then added the `repeated` argument later.

Comment: If this is the case, you can use this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842671/migrating-data-when-changing-an-ndb-fields-property-type/19848970#19848970  to retrieve the raw entities and fix the data

Comment: I didn't add the `repeated` argument after adding the entity.But i created a `Department` entity without the `employees` property first then deleted the entity from the datastore and then created a new Entity,this time after adding the `employees` property.

Answer (score 1):

dept.employees is expecting keys, and you are passing an Employee entity, it should be :

```
dept.employees.append(employee.key)
```

To add Employee entity directly, it should be defined this way in your Department Model :

```
employees = StructuredProperty(Employee, repeated=True)
```

It depends on how you wanna stucture your Application Data Model

Comment: so `employee.key` just gets the key for the Employee entity?

Comment: Absolutly, it returns a KeyProperty value which is what you defined in your Department Model

Comment: I think the `KeyProperty` is preferable for the purpose of my project because with the `StructuredProperty` option the object won't have its own ID or key

Comment: I haven't.I tried the solution you gave me,while the error has gone i am still not able to add the value to the entity.I am working on something new to test this solution on though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling `get_or_insert` with key_name as a keyword argument. However, it expects it as a positional argument. [See the docs here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert). Try this:

```
dept = Department.get_or_insert("Other Charges")
```