# ndb.TextProperty to ndb.StringProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

If I have a `Contact` model with the following definition:

```
class Contact(ndb.Model):

    name = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)

    website = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)

    location = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)
```

And entities in the datastore using that schema, will those entities "break" in any way by changing `TextProperty` to `StringProperty`?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19842671/584846

Answer (score 4):

First of all you don't need to use indexed=False for ndb.TextProperty, because it's [unindexed by default](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types)

If you want to change ndb.TextProperty to ndb.StringProperty you need to be sure that length of each field is less than 500 symblos(it's maximum length for StringProperty). Also, if you want to make either of properties indexed you'll need to remove `indexed=False` and re-put all of your entities to add them to index.

For re-putting you can use the following code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
def update_index(cursor=None):
    logging.info(cursor)
    q = Contact.query()
    contacts, cursor, more = q.fetch_page(100, start_cursor=cursor)
    ndb.put_multi(contacts)
    if more:
        deferred.defer(update_index, cursor)
```

Just don't forget to add

```
builtins:
- deferred: on
```

to your app.yaml file